# angular HttpClient with rxjs

Tags: angular, rest, rxjs, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to do a simple thing in angular 7.  I just need to call 1st a **getKey** REST api, then use the returned key to pass it to a 2nd REST api **getData** to get my data.  In the end I want my service to return an Observable so when all the process it completed I get the returned data.  Here my code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyTestServiceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData$(){

    return this.http.get("http://myservice/getKey").subscribe((key : string) => {

      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Key': key
        })
      };

      return this.http.get("http", httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
        return data;
      })

    });
  }
}
```

I know I'm doing it wrong since I return a subscription and not an Observable.  But just can't figure out how to do it.  Be gentle I'm just starting playing with RxJs and come from a AngularJs/promise background :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to first fetch a key and then use it in the second call to get data, `concatMap` is your pal as it relies on the previous observable to complete before going forward. `switchMap` is appropriate if you want to discard the previous observable stream and start a new one as soon as the previous stream emits a value.

So to apply this to your service:

```
getData$(): Observable<whatever you return in api here>{
    return this.http.get('getKeyUrl').pipe(
      concatMap(key => {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Key': key});
        return this.http.get('urlTwo', httpOptions)
      }) 
    )     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> You can use `switchMap` to achieve this -

```
   getData$(){
        return this.http.get("http://myservice/getKey").pipe(
          switchMap(key=>{
              const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Key': key
            })
          };
          return this.http.get("http", httpOptions);
          })
        );
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

On the service part :

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Key': key
    })
  };

  getData$(){

return this.http.get("http://myservice/getKey", httpOptions )

  }
```

---

and later in your component side:

```
 constructor(private myService: MyTestServiceService ) { }

 myMethodToCallMyService() {

   this.myService.getData$().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
 }
```

1. **Do not `subscribe` in your services classes.**
2. Export your `headerOptions` out of any service **(you can use a generic service to get them)**, since you'll use them in every service , then they should not depend on a specific one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switchMap` to achieve multiple `httpClient` calls and return data as `Observable` and you need to be familiar about `pipe` and `map` rxjs operators

Try like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyTestServiceService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 getData$(){
    return this.http.get("http://myservice/getKey").pipe(
      switchMap(key=>{
         return this.http.get("http", headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Key': key
        }));
      }));
  }
}
```

Hope this helps - check this libraries [rxjs](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library) - Happy coding :)